# MySQL query - addition, count and divide in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with column "Score", which holds a number ranging from 1 to 10. I need to achieve the following calculation in MySQL:

```
Column: Score
Row 1: 10
Row 2: 9
Row 3: 9
Row 4: 7
Row 5: 10
```

**Calculation: (Count of all scores >= 8) / (Count of all scores)**

Calculation: (4) / (5)

Result: 0.8

Result in percent: 80%

How can I achieve this in as little queries as possible to get the result of "80%"?

Comment: This is such a trivial question that I suspect there is more to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with this query:

```
SELECT SUM(Score >= 8) / COUNT(*) AS result, 
       SUM(Score >= 8) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS resultpercentage
FROM yourtable
```

It relies on the fact that MySQL treats boolean values as either 1 or 0 in a numeric context, so for every Score >= 8 we add one to the SUM.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b6c76b6e3845bc82469aeeb3a00895a4)

Comment: * 100 to get 80% with a cast to int and a concat to append %

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah - wasn't 100% clear OP wanted the raw number or percentage. Will edit anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here is another (and shorter) way to do it:

```
SELECT AVG(score >= 8) AS result FROM mytable
```

This gives you the results on a 0-1 scale. If you expect a result on a 0-100 scale, then:

```
SELECT AVG(score >= 8) * 100 AS result FROM mytable
```

You can also add the '%' sign with concatenation:

```
SELECT CONCAT(AVG(score >= 8) * 100, '%') AS result FROM mytable
```

Comment: @Armitage2k: possibly, since this avoids the need for a `COUNT(*)`. But you would need to assess it on a big dataset. On a small dataset, this will not make a difference whatsoever.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. I am dealing with a table with 130 columns and ~1200 rows, hence believe it could make a difference. Thank you for the insight.